# How to collect return values of methods in several Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm starting a new Thread for every Object in a list and invoking a method on those. The method I invoke returns a value which I want to save like that:

```
public int[] benchAll(){
    int[] numbers = new int[things.size()];
    for (final Thing thing: things) {
            final Generator generator = new Generator();

            new Thread(
                () -> generator.benchmark(thing)
            ).start();
            generators.add(generator);
        }
    return numbers;
    }
```

Now how can I save every return value of `benchmark()` in the other Threads to return it with this method `benchAll()`?

Your help'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` As Java specs says:

> An Executor that provides methods to manage termination and methods
>   that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more
>   asynchronous tasks.

So, using an implementation of `ExecutorService` you can run all your tasks asynchronously or synchronously in given number of threads. For that you need to create a list of `Callable` objects and pass it to `invokeAll` method of object of `ExecutorService`.
`invokeAll` method will return list of list of Future objects (Each Future object will represent each task, and order is same as you put in `Callable` list passed to `invokeAll` method) which you can loop total all the result of the task and print it.

You should read all available methods of `Executors` class which return different instances of `ExecutorService`, so choose the one which suits you.

In this way, you will be able to run your N tasks asynchronously in M threads, and once all the threads are finished you will get list of Future objects which will give you completion information/status of each task.
This result you can merge with other results/data and return from your method.

Check below psuedo example:

```
try {
    List<Callable<Object>> callableList = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
    callableList.add(null); /*Add instance of Callable*/
    callableList.add(null); /*Add instance of Callable*/
    callableList.add(null); /*Add instance of Callable*/

    //Specify how many threads you want or need to operate. Read other methods of Executors which return different instances of ExecutorService
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    //This will invoke all your N tasks in specified M threads ...
    List<Future<String[]>> futureObjects = service.invokeAll(callableList);  //futureObjects will contain result of each thread execution
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Various ways there are ...

Easy to implement, but not a good design: simply pass the array, and one index to each of your generator objects.

Then each generator just updates that position in the array.

Downside: hard to tell when they are all done; and as said: simply bad design (your generator code should not know about this array, much less about a specific index).

The better approach in Java in 2015: you want to read about [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interfaces. You can then use an ExecutorService; put that together, and all of a sudden your generators can actually return values. (still requires that your code does proper "house keeping" to understand when all "futures" were collected)